# Can someone with "send on behalf of" send to a restricted exchange distribution list?

Tags: exchange-2003, distribution-lists, restrictions

I have distribution list that where I have set Message restrictions to accept messages Only from a set of users. Some of these users have secretaries, which can send on behalf of their manager. If the manager can send to the distribution list can their secretaries send on behalf to the list as well? Or will I need to add the secretaries to list of "Only from:"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secretaries will be able to send to the list provided they are sending as the manager. They should not be able to send messages to the Distrubtion list otherwise! I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

**SendAs** and **SendonBehalf** permissions are two different things.

- For **SendAs** use, the Principal needs permission to send to the
  restricted DL.
- For **SendOnBehalf** use, the Delegate needs permissions
  to send to the restricted DL.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I have found regarding the subject, hope this helps:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8f56ca8-bd30-49e5-872f-a5691f7e44bf/wrong-not-permitted-mailtip-when-trying-to-send-onbehalfof-to-a-restricted-distribution-group?forum=exchangesvrclients

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.